# How to improve performance for large datasets with Realm?

Tags: swift, realm

My database has 500,000 records. The tables don't have a primary key because Realm doesn't support compound primary keys. I fetch data in background thread, then I want to display it in the UI on the main thread. But since Realm objects cannot be shared across threads I cannot use the record I fetched in the background. Instead I need to refetch the record on main thread? If I fetch a record out of the 500,000 records it will block the main thread. I don't know how to deal with it. I use Realm because it said it's enough quick. If I need refetch the record many times, is it really faster than SQLite? I don't want to create another property that combine other columns as primary key because the Realm database is already bigger than a SQLite file.

```
@objc class CKPhraseModel: CKBaseHMMModel{
    dynamic var pinyin :String!
    dynamic var phrase :String = ""

    class func fetchObjects(apinyin :String) -> Results<CKPhraseModel> {

        let realm = Realm.createDefaultRealm()

        let fetchString = generateQueryString(apinyin)
        let phrases = realm.objects(self).filter(fetchString).sorted("frequency", ascending: false)

        return phrases
    }

    func save(needTransition :Bool = true) {

        if let realm = realm {
            try! realm.write(needTransition) {[unowned self] in
                self.frequency += 1
            }
        }
        else {
            let realm = Realm.createDefaultRealm()
            if let model = self.dynamicType.fetchObjects(pinyin).filter("phrase == %@", phrase).first {
                try! realm.write(needTransition) {[unowned self] in
                    model.frequency += self.frequency
                }
            }
            else {
                try! realm.write(needTransition) {[unowned self] in
                    realm.add(self)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then I store fetched records in Array

```
let userInput = "input somthing"
let phraseList = CKPhraseModel().fetchObjects(userInput)
for (_,phraseModel) in phraseList.enumerate() {
     candidates.append(phraseModel)
}
```

Then I want to display `candidates` information in UI when the user clicks one of these.  I will call CKPhraseModel's `save` function to save changes. This step is on main thread.

Comment: Realm works perfectly fine with MainThread & Background thread. The issue is you can not pass Realm, RealmObject or RealmResults across threads. So, in your use case, get the records from background thread store the data in background thread in Realm, and fetch the records from Realm in mainThread with ASYNC methods of Realm.

Comment: Follow this example if you are looking for some actual code https://github.com/viraj49/Realm_android-injection-rx-test

Comment: @VirajTank I fetch the records from background thread. Then I store fetched records in a Array. I display it on UI. If user click one of those. I store it in background thread in Realm. The thread line is like this : `background thread => main thread => background thread`, If I fetch same record many times. whether it reduce app performance ? My app execute the process with user input a word.So it's very frequent to fetch data and store data with big database.

Comment: Of course it reduces the performance avoid doing it. This flow looks fine except why are you fetching gain when user click on one of the record, why don't you use the Array you stored the data in the beginning.

Comment: @VirajTank Yes, I store fetched records in Array. But I can't use it in main thread. And I can't use it in store data background thread. I'm comfused.

Comment: If the fetched records Array is not RealmObject/RealmResult then you can share it between background & mainThread, no problem. Can you share the code so it's easier to pinpoint exact problem.

Comment: @VirajTank Yes, I will share the code tomorrow. I am off duty now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117267/discussion-between-kai-and-viraj-tank).

Comment: @VirajTank I have share the main code.

Answer (score 1):

Realm is fast if you use its lazy loading capability, which means that you create a filter that would return your `candidates` directly from the Realm, because then you'd need to only retrieve only the elements you index in the results.

In your case, you copy ALL elements out. That's kinda slow, which is why you end up freezing.

Comment: If I don't execute `let userInput = "input somthing"
let phraseList = CKPhraseModel().fetchObjects(userInput)
for (_,phraseModel) in phraseList.enumerate() {
     candidates.append(phraseModel)
}` to copy result. How can I show the candidate in UI in main thread ? The Results are fetched in background thread. I can't understand. How should I do ?

Comment: ...but if the results are copied and fetched from the background to the UI, then this shouldn't even freeze. The error is elsewhere.

Comment: When I execute the for loop, I change it to create a new `CKPhraseModel` that isn't managed by Realm to copy  all `phraseModel`'s properties in `phraseList`. So I can use it in UI thread. Because the object isn't managed by Realm,I can use it across thread. I don't have any good ideal to deal with it. I don't know whether I'm misunderstand realm!

Comment: Well, you should read a bit more about Realm queries here: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries